# CSS property border-bottom-image is not working?

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS code:

```
.header-text {
   -moz-border-bottom-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
   -webkit-border-bottom-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
   -o-borderbottom-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
 }
```

And my HTML code:

```
<div>
  <h1 class="header-text" >let's Knockout Poverty in India!</h1>
</div>
```

Why is my border image not showing?

Comment: Please format your code properly, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to use our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I don't see if there is a `-moz-border-bottom-image` property, you probably need `-moz-border-image`. It allows you to set border-width so you can do something like

```
-moz-border-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 0 0 27 0 stretch stretch;
```

if you need only a bottom border, and the same for all other properties.

Comment: There is a border-bottom-image property officially in CSS3, however browsers only support the shorthand at the moment.

Ref: http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-border-properties/#biimage

Answer (score 2):

You can then hide the top, right and left borders using:

```
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; /* Safari 5 */
    -o-border-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; /* Opera */
    border-image: url('images/tour_tab_border.gif') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
```