# Border image for just the bottom using CSS

Tags: border, css

I am wanting to use an image as a border but just for the bottom - can this be achieved in CSS? I have briefly researched it and im reading about slices etc but I dont quite understand it.

I thought there might be something like border-bottom-image or similar to that...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use border image only for bottom border? Our CSS seems to replicate the image across the whole div instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164393/use-border-image-only-for-bottom-border-our-css-seems-to-replicate-the-image-ac)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337566/why-doesnt-the-border-bottom-image-css-property-work

Comment: Infact it doesnt solve my problem because the problem on that page was never solved itself..

Comment: Well you could still do it the old-fashioned way by throwing a div into your container, position it absolutely at the bottom and using it as an 'image-border'. Probably also safer for cross-browser atm

Comment: @user1278496 Which one? Try `-moz-border-image: url('image URL here') 0 0 27 0 stretch stretch;` in firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make your HTML something like this:

```
<div class="container block">
   <div class="content block">
      <---!Putt content here!--->
       <div class="border-bottom block">
           <---!Make it empty!--->
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then make the css something like this:

```
.block
{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width: xpx; /*choose your width (x) */
}

border-bottom
{
  background: url('picture url');
}
```

**ps:** you can repeat this as much as you want and you'll have always the style for those classes (just copy and past the HTML code)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps think of this in another way. You want an image to appear along the bottom of an element. It might *look* like a border, but it doesn't have to be *called* one. An easy way to get the visual effect you are seeking is to place some padding on the element and place the image as a background image in that padding area. E.g.

```
element {padding-bottom: 20px; background: url(bgimage.png) no-repeat 50% 100%;}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this css property:

```
border:solid;
border-bottom-width:10px; //thickness of border
border-image:url(image.jpg) 0 0 20 0 repeat; //20 is length of your image
```