# Setting Image for border-bottom property

Tags: css

We all know that

```
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
```

will make the bottom border 2px thick and color will be black

but can we do any such thing like for the border bottom we can set an image

that means a thin horizontal image will be the bottom-line border of the div??

thanks in advance

Comment: This article should give you all the information you need - http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337566/why-doesnt-the-border-bottom-image-css-property-work) should help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

`border-image`, might be what you seek, but it`s CSS3. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp .

I would set `positon:relative;` on the container `<div>` and use `position:absolute; bottom:0;` for your `<img />` inside the container.

Comment: Linking to W3Schools? yikes.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate the image border-bottom by setting the image by something like

```
background: url(...) bottom repeat-x;
```

or

```
background: url(...) bottom no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 3px;
```

Unlike the actual `border-image`, this will work in IE (IE7+ for the first example, IE9+ for the latter one).